# How do you properly pass arguments with push named in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm having an error while passing arguments and receiving arguments in flutter

Here is the class I'm trying to pass and change its value:

```
class Addtx {
  double? balance;
  var selectedDate;
  String? category;
  String? note;

  Addtx({
    @required this.balance,
    @required this.selectedDate,
    @required this.category,
    @required this.note,
  });
}
```

Here are the routes in the main file:

```
routes: {
    feedPage.route: (context) => feedPage(),
    newExpense.route: (context) => newExpense(),
    AddExpense.route: (context) => AddExpense(),
},
```

So here is where I use the value and store the balance. Not sure if this is the correct way to store it, but I couldn't debug because of the error I was having.

```
TextField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 35.0, color: Colors.white),
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        filled: false,
        hintText: '_ _ , _ _',
        hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 150.0, bottom: 8.0, top: 8.0),
        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
            //borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.7),
        ),
    ),
    onChanged: (value) => Addtx(balance: double.parse(value)),
),
```

Here is where I pass the value I just made (not sure how to send the value I made so I hard coded it):

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, feedPage.route, arguments: Addtx(balance: 5));
```

Here is where I receive the values:

```
class _AddExpenseState extends State<AddExpense> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        final arf = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Addtx;
        return Container(
...
```

The problem is in this line of code: `final arf = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Addtx;`. The debug console error:

```
The following _CastError was thrown building AddExpense(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _AddExpenseState#1f0ec):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Addtx' in type cast
```

[image: Image of the error in the emulator]

Just to note, I'm still quite new to Flutter.

Comment: You don't get any errors with `Addtx(balance: 5)` or `Addtx(balance: double.parse(value))`? These constructors miss required parameters and there is a non-nullable member  `selectedDate` that is not initalized.

Comment: even if i comment these Addtx(balance: 5) / Addtx(balance: double.parse(value)) i still get the same error

Comment: if `ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments` is null, it can't converted to type `Addtx`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to get arguments in the router itself. Like this

```
routes: {
    feedPage.route: (context) => feedPage(),
    newExpense.route: (context) => newExpense(),
    AddExpense.route: (context) {
     final arf = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as Addtx;
     return AddExpense(arf);
    },
  },
```

Also, u need to create a proper constructor for ur widget.

```
class AddExpense extends StatefulWidget {

AddExpense(this.addTx);

final Addtx addTx;

...
}
```